# app dieing in android kitkat network issue

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-networking

app is running fine in gingerbread but dieing in kikat.Here is logcat:

```
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Process: com.example.barcodescanningapp, PID: 1038
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-06 07:57:21.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
```

error seems to be with network request but why this happening in kikat and not in gingenbread.

code for network request :

```
item_name_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        item_quantity_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);

        item_name = item_name_view.getText().toString();
        Log.w("item name", item_name);
        item_quantity = item_quantity_view.getText().toString();
        // Creating HTTP client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SUBMISSION_URL);


        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", scanContent));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", item_name));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", item_quantity));

        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            //response_text.setText(getResponseBody(response).replaceAll("<.*>", " "));
            response_text.setText(getResponseBody(response));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

app is giving request via post to a server and receiving response to be displayed in an activity. This is all working fine in gingerbread nut app gets crashing when request is made to network.

Comment: show us some code. Post only relevant parts though

Comment: code is online now @Ploutox